# Python NetworkX: edges based on indices

Tags: python, networkx

I want to connect nodes based on the index of arrays. An example:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["N1","N2","N3","N4","N5"])

set1 = {'A1':np.array([1,0,1,1,0])}
set1["A2"] = np.array([1,1,1,0,1])
set1["A3"]= np.array([0,0,0,0,1])
set1["A4"] = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
```

I created a graph `G` with five nodes (N1 ... N5) and a dictionary `set1` with four keys (A1 ... A5). The values for the keys are numpy arrays with the length 5 and the values 0 or 1. Every entry corresponds to a node. All nodes with 1 should be connected with edges.  E.g. `A1 = [1,0,1,1,0]`: The node N1 should be connected with N3, N1 with N4 and N3 with N4. The same for A2, A3 and A4.

Therefore, I tried the following:

```
for key, value in set1.items():
    position = np.where(value)
    for x in np.nditer(position[0]):
        #G.add_edge(names


#nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

I stuck here - would be great, if someone could help me.

Answer (score 3):

An easier representation is probably an [adjacency matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_array.html), which describes all of the edges in the graph (weights, which can just be 0/1).

For this, you need to represent your edges differently, e.g.

```
# adding all-zeros from node 5, since the example dict has no A5 entry
adj = np.array([[1,0,1,1,0], [1,1,1,0,1], [0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,0,1], [0,0,0,0,0]])

G1 = nx.from_numpy_array(adj)
# some relabelling because the nodes are automatically given integer labels
mapping = {k:"N{}".format(k+1) for k in G1.nodes()}
G1 = nx.relabel_nodes(G1, mapping)
```

If you have some other reason why the edge data has to remain in a dictionary, and you don't want to produce an adjacency matrix, you could use the following procedure:

```
for key, value in set1.items():
    # get the source node name, Nx from the key Ax
    source_node = key.replace("A", "N")
    # and the list of targets
    tgt_nodes = np.where(value)[0]
    for tgt_i in tgt_nodes:
        # construct target - note that python arrays are zero-indexed#
        # and your node list starts at 1.
        tgt_node = "N{}".format(tgt_i +1)

        G.add_edge(source_node, tgt_node)
```

now lets draw the two with same layout:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,sharex=True, sharey=True)    
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, ax=ax[0], pos=pos)
nx.draw(G1, with_labels=True, ax=ax[1], pos=pos)
```

[image: two equivalent graphs]